# Trying to call SharePoint 2010 List.asmx service. SharePoint 2010 is using Azure AD Application Proxy

Tags: sharepoint-2010, authorization, asmx, azure-active-directory, bearer-token

Our SharePoint 2010 site is now using Azure AD Application Proxy for a single sign-on solution.

We have an Azure Web Job trying to access the SharePoint 2010 List.asmx service.

We added the List.asmx service as a Web Application to Azure AD.

We are able to get a bearer token for the List.asmx service.

```cs
var apiClientId = "XXXXXXXX-8ceb-452b-abec-b85a784fbfb5";
enter code herevar apiAppKey = "XXXXXXXXlx0ZJynQ8mmICeX454VrtOkxa0qqIZuKQY8=";
var apiResourceId = "https://sharepoint2010baseurl.com/_vti_bin/lists.asmx";
var tenant = "XXXXXXXX-debb-41a6-9c78-0516c185fa0d";
var aadInstance = "https://login.windows.net/{0}";

authority = String.Format(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, aadInstance, tenant);

var authContext = new AuthenticationContext(authority);
if (authContext.TokenCache.ReadItems().Count() > 0)
    authContext = new AuthenticationContext(authContext.TokenCache.ReadItems().First().Authority);

var clientCredential = new ClientCredential(apiClientId, apiAppKey);
var authResult = await authContext.AcquireTokenAsync(apiResourceId, clientCredential);

Assert.IsNotNull(authResult.AccessToken);
```

After adding the bearer token to the RequestMessage Header of the SoapClient call, we get an error.

```cs
var soapClient = new ListsSoapClient();
soapClient.ClientCredentials.UserName.UserName = "BasicUserName";
soapClient.ClientCredentials.UserName.Password = "BasicPassword";

const string listName = "Announcements";

using (new OperationContextScope(soapClient.InnerChannel))
{

    HttpRequestMessageProperty requestMessage = new HttpRequestMessageProperty();
    requestMessage.Headers["Content-Type"] = "text/xml";
    requestMessage.Headers[System.Net.HttpRequestHeader.Authorization] = "Bearer " + authResult.AccessToken;
    OperationContext.Current.OutgoingMessageProperties[HttpRequestMessageProperty.Name] = requestMessage;

    var query = new XElement("Query", "");
    var viewFields = new XElement("ViewFields",
        new XElement("FieldRef", new XAttribute("Name", "ID")),
        new XElement("FieldRef", new XAttribute("Name", "Title")),
        new XElement("FieldRef", new XAttribute("Name", "Body")),      
    );
    var queryOptions = new XElement("QueryOptions", "");

    var result = soapClient.GetListItems(listName, null, null, viewFields, null, null, null);

    Assert.IsNotNull(result, "Results were null.");
}
```

The error message we are receiving is as follows:

> The HTTP request is unauthorized with client authentication scheme 'Basic'. The authentication header received from the server was 'Bearer realm="XXXXXXXX-debb-41a6-9c78-0516c185fa0d",authorization_uri="https://login.microsoftonline.com/XXXXXXXX-debb-41a6-9c78-0516c185fa0d/oauth2/authorize",trusted_issuers="00000001-0000-0000-c000-000000000000@*",client_id="XXXXXXXX-f826-46d2-a221-ba9908427c8f"'.

The underlying question here is how do you call an asmx service with an Azure AD bearer token?